# Using Chef, limiting user access to certain servers/environments

Tags: chef-infra

I've got a use case where I have a contractor who needs ssh and sudo access to one server, but not to our other servers. All of our servers are managed by Chef, and we use databags to configure each user. Any tips on the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, there is a large variety of possibilities :-)
[Here is](https://github.com/typo3-cookbooks/t3-base#users), how we configure per-node user access based on a `users` data bag.

- All users with `group: sysadmin` are automatically assigned to all nodes with *sudo* privileges.
- All other users are added based on their assignment to particular hosts. The `users` data bag is
  searched for items that contain an entry for `node['fqdn']` in the `"nodes"` key of the data bag:

```
{
    "id": "a-srv123-admin",
    ...
    "nodes": {
            "srv123.typo3.org": {
                    "sudo": "true"
            }
    }
}
```

In order to remove a user from all nodes, `action: remove` can be set
on the highest level:

```
{
    "id": "a-user-to-remove",
    "action": "remove"
}
```

In order to remove a user from a certain node, `action: remove` can be set
on the node level:

```
{
    "id": "a-user-to-remove",
    ...
    "nodes": {
            "srv123.typo3.org": {
                    "action": "remove"
            }
    }
}
```

The [implementation of this](https://github.com/TYPO3-cookbooks/t3-base/blob/31d8f1a4d324f3b9cddc623505f989ffc627aca0/recipes/_users.rb#L33-L109) (not very clean in truth, unfortunately), just searches for all users associated with the `node[fqdn]`:

```rb
node_attribute = "fqdn"
log "Searching for users associated with node #{node[node_attribute]}"
begin
  users = search(users_databag_name, "nodes:#{node[node_attribute]}")
rescue Net::HTTPServerException
  Chef::Log.warn "Searching for users in the 'users' databag failed, search for users associated with node '#{node[node_attribute]}'"
  users = {}
end

users.each do |u|
  node_options = u['nodes'][node[node_attribute]]
  Chef::Log.info "Got node options: #{node_options}"
  if u['action'] == "remove" || node_options['action'] == "remove"
    user u['username'] ||= u['id'] do
      action :remove
    end
  else
    # snip...

    # Create user object.
    user u['username'] do
      uid u['uid'] if u['uid']
      gid u['gid'] if u['gid']
      shell u['shell']
      comment u['comment']
      password u['password'] if u['password']
      supports manage_home: true
      home home_dir
      action u['action'] if u['action']
    end

    # sudo management
    if node_options['sudo'] == "true"
      sudo u['username'] do
        nopasswd true
        user u['username']
      end
    else
      sudo u['username'] do
        action :remove
      end
    end
  end
end
```

EDIT: Be warned that any user with access to Chef's client certificate can query data based on what the client can read. This can include passwords that are stored in other node's attributes. RBAC or chef-vault can mitigate this.